# Error at to Install nvidia drivers in Asus ROG G553VD

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus, 17.10, nvidia-geforce

I have a notebook Asus ROG G553VD and I just finished to install ubuntu 17.10,  downloaded Nvidia drivers from official website but when I triying to install throw this error

```
Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 384.98.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
ERROR: Unable to find the development tool `cc` in your path; please make sure that you have the package 'gcc' installed.  If gcc is installed on your system, then please check that `cc` is in your PATH.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

what is a package 'gcc' and how to install this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is a C compiler. You can install it by running `sudo apt install gcc` in Terminal.